# Two Ubuntu 14.04 share data through lan port

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to share some big data through Lan port in my two Ubuntu 14.04 pcs.

Is there any tutorial I can find so that I can step by step setting up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, You could use `netcat` commands.

**Source**

Open socket to send a file:

```
cat file | ncat -v -l -p 5989
```

source is ready to send data through port `5989`

**Destination**

Go to destination machine and read data from source (192.168.1.10) which is sending data on port 5989 in above command

```
 ncat 192.168.1.10 5989 > file
```

Note that `192.168.1.10` is source IP entered from destination machine. Read further here:[Netcat Tutorials](http://www.binarytides.com/netcat-tutorial-for-beginners/)

**EDIT:**

I just noticed that you said Big Data. How big the data is? Netcat will work really well for any size as long as you have stable connection. But for big files it is recommended to have tools which could handle interrupted transfers. You could look into [Rsync](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-rsync-to-sync-local-and-remote-directories-on-a-vps)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest `NFS` (Network file system) which permits you to mount/umount filesystems with file and directory permissions.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo